# Determine current Mac Safari web page using Python

Tags: python, macos, safari

Is there a way to determine programmatically, using Python, which web page is currently active in Safari?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An Applescript example is [here](http://daringfireball.net/2003/01/scripting_safari_urls), and the relevant part is:

```
tell application "Safari"
    set url_list to URL of every document
end tell
```

Python/AppleScript translation is covered [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/AppleScript).  E.g., install appscript as described [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/install.html):

```
sudo easy_install appscript
```

and then, as shown [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Safari), you can do e.g.:

```
>>> import appscript
>>> print appscript.app("Safari").windows.first.current_tab.URL()
http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/Safari
```

Comment: Thank you! Unequivocally and precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: @Alex One caveat of this solution is that whenever I have it running a Python application icon pops up bouncing in the dock. If I close the application, it closes my python script, so I know the two are related. 

I'm wondering if you know a way for me to run the script without getting the Python program in the dock.

Comment: Does the bouncing happen if you are running your script with a `Terminal.app`?  Or how else are you packaging your `.py` file to obtain the "unwanted bounce" effect?

Comment: It happens whether I run the `.py` script in `Terminal.app`, `TextMate.app`, or as a `launchd` agent. And just so it is unambiguous, the primary problem is that I don't want Python to be in the dock (i.e. I want the script to run quietly in the background).

Comment: @credford, I'm perplexed -- I run py scripts in Terminal all the time and don't see the bounce. Don't think we can solve it in these cramped comment boxes:-(.  Please open another Q giving a minimal example that bounces when run from the terminal and both myself and others will strive to help, as usual on SO -- thanks.

Comment: @Alex Thanks! I'll post a question withen the next few days.